# Delete lock in table - Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I want to lock a table "PROCESS" to stop other users from deleting the contents of the table.

I have gone through some forums but not able to conclude how the lock works and how to lock the table.

Can anyone please tell me how to put this in sql query format?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9015.htm#SQLRF01605

Answer (score 3):

1. `LOCK TABLE <table name> IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` - it will lock table till COMMIT/ROLLBACK
2. `ALTER TABLE <table name> READ ONLY` - it will prevent all DML operations (not only deletions) until you get table back to READ WRITE

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#CJAHHIBI

Comment: Thank you:) Also please tell me How to bring back to normal mode?

Comment: Will this work??                                                                                                           "DISABLE TABLE LOCK" - to disable lock

Comment: @vkreddy. No, it won't. DISABLE LABLE LOCK prevents DDL operations, not DML. See the documentation please: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53446.